# I am getting the following error while publishing c#.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, publishing

I am getting the following error while publishing a c#.net website ::

> An assembly with the same simple name 'App_Code, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>        PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or 
>        sign them to enable side-by-side.

Answer (score -2):

You have code in the App_Code folder, that is duplicated somewhere else in your project. 
Is this a Web Application Project or a Web Site type Project?  Usually in a Web Application Project there would be no need to have any code files in the App_Code folder.

Comment: To people down-voting: A new user is trying to help others. If you down-vote his answers, be courteous and let him know why so he can improve. Thanks.